# viewDidLoad using Persistence

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have problem with my Iphone project in viewDidLoad event the app crash on

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
```

I am trying to store information from text Filed    can someone help me to solve the problem

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            UITextField *theField = self.lineFields[i];
            theField.text = array[i];
        }
        NSData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc]
                        initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc]
                                         initForReadingWithData:data];
        BIDThreeLines *threelines = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:kRootKey];
        [unarchiver finishDecoding];

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            UITextField *theField = self.lineFields[i];
            theField.text = threelines.lines[i];
        }
    }

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(applicationWillResignActive:)
     name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
     object:app];
}
Error 
2013-03-25 23:29:45.592 MobilePaymentsApp[1182:c07] -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d0e8d0
2013-03-25 23:29:45.593 MobilePaymentsApp[1182:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d0e8d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c96012 0x10d3e7e 0x1d214bd 0x1c85bbc 0x1c8594e 0x1c0ae18 0xb030e8 0x339c 0xf91c7 0xf9232 0x483d5 0x4876f 0x48905 0x51917 0x2cc5 0x15157 0x15747 0x1694b 0x27cb5 0x28beb 0x1a698 0x1bf1df9 0x1bf1ad0 0x1c0bbf5 0x1c0b962 0x1c3cbb6 0x1c3bf44 0x1c3be1b 0x1617a 0x17ffc 0x29fd 0x2925)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

https://github.com/a-elnajjar/MobilePaymentsApp

Comment: which lines throwing the error, check with breakpoint

Comment: NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc]
                                         initForReadingWithData:data];

Comment: @AnoopVaidya can you see the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSKeyedArchiver returns object that you have stored in it. eg. if you have stored an array then it will return an array. so be careful while unarchiveing objects.

in following example i have read an array from NSKeyedUnarchiver.

```
NSData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSArray *arr = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Answer (score -1):

> Look in the crash log's stack trace to see where exactly this call is
>   happening.
>
> If the variable you're sending -row to isn't actually typed as an
>   NSArray, it's likely that you've failed to follow the memory
>   management rules for that variable. These same symptoms are very
>   commonly caused by that. Something that responds to -row could have
>   existed at one point, been deallocated because you didn't -retain it,
>   and then an NSArray was later allocated in that spot.
>
> Run a "Build & Analyze," and re-re-review the memory management
>   guidelines until you know them in your sleep.

Source: [[NSCFArray row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3953a20](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3106401/1756131)

Comment: I read these whole answer somewhere else, and surely **it was not by You** :D

Comment: @AnoopVaidya- then wt ur problem ?? here main pont is that need to solve OP's Problem

Comment: @iPatel:then you can also give the link to that answer + your comments if any . That would be nice.

Comment: There is a flag called **Duplicate answer**. If this is flagged and you found doing quite regularly, you may be in trouble. And if you think this is already answered them simply vote to close with the link. Its not a bad thing to get idea and form your new answer with something more added. Dont get hurt, but see this in positive.

Comment: @iPatel whenever you are quoting someone, make sure you mark that text as being a quote - plagiats are punished very harshly!

Comment: @MicRO: [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168873/duplicate-or-bad-answer) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51347/duplicate-answers-are-tolerated)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Thanks Anoop, I just made an edit to your edit,you are free to revert it if you feel it uncomfortable

Comment: @MicRO: you should show the title name not some random ids. And that was added by Till, not me.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya oh..is it so...ok..thats why I asked such a silly question, because I didn't find anything as such here! Thanks :-)